# How to limit Apache MPM Prefork processes per user in FreeBSD?

Tags: apache, limit, freebsd, jail

I am using `FreeBSD 10.3-BETA` with `Apache-2.4.18 MPM Prefork`. Apache lives inside a jail with `devfs`, `procfs`, `fdescfs`, `/home` mounted via `nullfs` and `/etc/{passwd,group,*db,login.conf}` (and other same files) actual copy.

I could not find any `MaxWorkersPerUser`-like directive in ApacheMPM documentation, so I'm trying to limit it via FreeBSD limiting system.

I have some limits in `login.conf` for any user, like:

```
# limits -U littej
Resource limits for class coolguy:
  cputime                    90 secs
  filesize             infinity kB
  datasize             infinity kB
  stacksize            infinity kB
  coredumpsize                0 kB
  memoryuse              524288 kB
  memorylocked               64 kB
  maxprocesses               30
  openfiles            infinity
  sbsize               infinity bytes
  vmemoryuse             757760 kB
  pseudo-terminals     infinity
  swapuse              infinity kB
```

When I'm trying to create more processes then allowed, I have standard error:

```
littej@home $ for i in {1..30}; do sleep 60& done
[1] 7394
..
[28] 7421
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

But if i will connect to my site, apache process spawns from my user - and holds on. So, with limit of `maxprocesses=30`, I can spawn up to `ServerLimit` apache-processes.
And all of them have limits about `maxproccesses=30`:

```
# pgrep -fu littej|wc -l; for i in `pgrep -fu littej`;  do procstat -l $i|grep maxproc|grep -v sleep; done
      120
9857 httpd            maxprocesses              30               30     
<..all of them are same with different PIDS..>  
9848 httpd            maxprocesses              30               30     
7412 bash             maxprocesses              30               30     
7137 sh               maxprocesses              30               30
```

Then I've tryed to use `rctl` limiting. All the same, even rctl shows it should limit maxproc to 30 but allowing like tripple more:

```
# rctl -a user:littej:maxproc:deny=30
# rctl
user:littej:maxproc:deny=30
<..some other system users..>
# rctl -u user:littej|grep maxproc
maxproc=80
```

(digits are not same with `pgrep|wc` since system lives and I did not collect all stats immediately)
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advice.

Comment: I've added `MaxClientsVHost 10` to httpd.cond, nothing changes. It still can fork as many apaches, as it wants.

Comment: Same on `RLimitNPROC`. Sorry for spamming it, I've tryed to resolve it before posting for two days, but still trying.